# How to set a query pattern using the queryExpr property in the djFilteringSelect control in XPages

Tags: xml, dojo, xpages

I am trying to tweak the djFilteringSelect control in XPages so that when a user type a query it finds any occurance of the char sequence, not just from the beginning.

so if the selectitems contain a value "this is a product" and I type product it should be a match. the default is that it only searches from the beginning of the text.

there is a queryExpr property that can be used for this but the documentation is lacking for use in XPages. I have tried the following and a lot others but cannot get it to work.

```
<xe:this.queryExpr><![CDATA[#{javascript:"*{0}*"}]]></xe:this.queryExpr>
<xe:this.queryExpr><![CDATA[#{javascript:"$*{0}*"}]]></xe:this.queryExpr>
```

```
<xe:djFilteringSelect id="djFilteringSelect1">
<xp:selectItems id="selectItems2">
    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var products = @DbLookup("","LookUp", "Produkt", 2);
products = @Unique(@Trim(products));
return products.sort();}]]></xp:this.value>
                        </xp:selectItems>
</xe:djFilteringSelect>
```

here is a complete example if anyone want to copy/paste into a new XPage, I want to type "x" and the entry "my name is x" should show up

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom"
    xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">
    
    <xe:djFilteringSelect id="djFilteringSelect1">
        
        <xp:selectItem itemLabel="my name is x"></xp:selectItem>
        <xp:selectItem itemLabel="my name is y"></xp:selectItem>
        <xp:selectItem itemLabel="my name is z"></xp:selectItem>
    </xe:djFilteringSelect>
</xp:view>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use `djFilteringSelect` in our application and it's working as intented. The only point to note is that some characters in the string must be escaped: therefore the correct values for `queryExpr` is `"*\$\{0\}*"`.

The explanation why `$` and `{}` must be escaped can be found here https://xcellerant.wordpress.com/2014/07/22/changing-search-behavior-of-dojo-filtering-select-in-xpages/

Comment: thanks, can you add a complete example based on my example above because I could not get it to work

Comment: @ThomasAdrian this works: `<xe:djFilteringSelect id="djFilteringSelect1" queryExpr="#{javascript:return '*\$\{0\}*';}" autoComplete="false">`

Answer (score 1):

djFilteringSelect is just a wrapper for the Dojo FilteringSelect component, so `queryExpr` and `searchExpr` are just used to pass to the underlying (client-side) JavaScript code. So for documentation, Dojo site is a good source. According to the API documentation `*${0}*` should do what you want (https://dojotoolkit.org/api/?qs=1.6/dijit/form/FilteringSelect). The docs talk about combining with highlightMatch to define what's highlighted.

Comment: thanks but I have already tried that, it just messes up the dropdown
<xe:djFilteringSelect id="djFilteringSelect1" queryExpr="*${0}*">

Comment: stars in comment removed by stackoverflow :-)